# Как получить количество секунд с начала дня JS?

Tags: javascript

При вызове функции second() необходимо передать в переменную time количество секунд с начала дня

```
function second() {
var time = ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из текущей даты берем часы, минуты и секунды и складываем. Подробнее можно здесь посмотреть https://learn.javascript.ru/date

```js
const date = new Date();
const seconds = date.getHours() * 3600 + date.getMinutes() * 60 + date.getSeconds();
console.log(seconds);
```

Comment: И иногда и кое-где это будет прекрасно глючить ‍♂️

Comment: Потому что не учитывает летнее время

Comment: Не знаю, в каком случае этот метод глючит, но мою проблему решил. Большое спасибо :)